# downloaded txt file become shrinked

Tags: java, servlets, file-io, download, encryption

I am trying to write a txt file with my servlet and send it to my desktop app. The desktop app saves the file on local disk. There is no problem with downloading big binary files but txt files which are small miss final characters.

For example, servlet sends txt file whose length is 523KB, but when I save it on my desktop app the file length is 496KB?

Here is the servlet code:

```
final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
byte buffer[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

for (int nread = 0; (nread = in.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, nread);
}

out.flush();
out.close();
in.close();
```

And here is the desktop app code (I use HttpClient 4):

```
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
resEntity = response.getEntity();
InputStream in = resEntity.getContent();
in = new CipherInputStream(in, decipher);//maybe the aes block missing here...
FileOutputStream out= new FileOutputStream(path);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int numRead = 0;

while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}

out.flush();
out.close();
```

And the decipher defined the same as for encryping...:

```
  KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
          kgen.init(128);
          key = kgen.generateKey();

    byte[] ivar = new byte[]
                      {
                          0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09,0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f
                  };
AlgorithmParameterSpec params = new IvParameterSpec(ivar );
dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, params );
```

Please help me to understand why I lose some characters of text files?

Comment: differences in line-ending characters (\n vs \r\n)?  Have you actually compared the files to see what's different?

Comment: well, the file get shrinked within a word like a...

Comment: Original: Mr Brown was able to get abroad every 3 months but he couldn't leave his dog
Downloaded: Mr Brown was able to get abroad every 3 mon

Comment: So as you can see just within a word :(

Comment: Show the declarations of `in` and `out` on both sides

Comment: I have added the declarations of in and out :)

Comment: As I was saying, it downloads binary files fine except the txt :( I don't get it why txt file is something special thing or what?

Comment: I would suggest that you examine the data flow using Wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org/) to see if the truncation is occurring on the sending or receiving side.

Comment: But why txt files get shrinked only?

Comment: Video and images download fine :( All get downloaded fine except txt

Comment: Oh, my... Does anyone ever faced the same problem? Or txt format is the most rare format in the world? :)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the binary files are handled OK ? I mean, have you compared the original and downloaded with diff or something or you just saw that it works in your office application.

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded video,audio,images and doc files and I know their original content so they all are not corrupted. But the downloaded txt files are all missing final text. I can open txt file but it missing text :( For some reason as for txt files I can download just 496kb from 523kb :( I don't know the reason so I need your advice very much.

Comment: Maybe there is a final chunk problem but I don't know why is the problem occures with txt files only? :(

Comment: For example I have just downloaded a txt file so its original length is 1722bytes but the downloaded version contains 1696bytes ... So where I could lost its final 26 bytes ?

Comment: Yes it is the original my IDE code :)

Comment: But I don't get it... why all files can be downloaded OK except the txt. When I download txt files they are always missing some ending text :(

Comment: How is the decipher object defined?

Comment: byte[] iva = new byte[]
                  {
                          0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09,0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f
                  };
AlgorithmParameterSpec params = new IvParameterSpec(iva);
dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

Answer (score 1):

The servlet example code is writing bytes directly to the output stream, but the desktop app sample code is decrypting what it reads.  If the desktop is decrypting data that is not encrypted, the results could be unpredictable.

Comment: No, the data was encrypted before with the same key.

Comment: And there is no problem with all files except the txt format :( I didn't check the pdf but txt is  a real badluck

Comment: I guess it is some AES decryption block missing because all txt files get lost 15-16 characters. It is the 128 bits or something and according to the code kgen.init(128);
... I don't know how to fix it. Please help