# Cannot download the whole decrypted txt file

Tags: java, file-io, iostream, encryption

I am writing a small test app. The thing is... Servlet downloads any AES encrypted file to my desktop app. Then my desktop app decrypts it and saves on local hdd. It working fine as for binary video, images etc but for some reason I get lost characters from txt files. As I can get it, any txt file is missing its 128 final bits (it is 15 or 16 final characters).

I don't know why that happens so I need your advice

Here is the servlet code:

```
final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
byte buffer[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

for (int nread = 0; (nread = in.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, nread);
}

out.flush();
out.close();
in.close();
```

And the desktop app code snippet:

```
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);//it is HttpClient 4...
resEntity = response.getEntity();
InputStream in = resEntity.getContent();
in = new CipherInputStream(in, decipher);//maybe the aes block missing here...
FileOutputStream out= new FileOutputStream(path);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int numRead = 0;

while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}

out.flush();
out.close();
```

And thats how I get decipher:

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
          kgen.init(128);
          key = kgen.generateKey();

    byte[] ivar = new byte[]
                      {
                          0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09,0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f
                  };
AlgorithmParameterSpec params = new IvParameterSpec(ivar );
dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, params );
```

... And here is the desktop app upload snippet

```
HttpPost httppost = null;
        HttpResponse response=null;
        HttpEntity resEntity=null;

        try {
          File file = filePath;
          fileLength=file.length();

          HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.
                                              PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                                              HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);


          String url="http://localhost:8080/testUrl";
          httppost = new HttpPost(url);

String name=file.getName();
InputStreamBody inputStreamBody=new InputStreamBody(new FileInputStream(file),name);

MultiPartEntity multiPartEntity = new MultiPartEntity();
multiPartEntity .addPart("file-name", new StringBody(name, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
multiPartEntity .addPart("file-stream", inputStreamBody);
```

and the InputStreamBody writeTo method (you can see the doc here http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/clover/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/InputStreamBody.html)...

```
    byte[] ivar = new byte[]
                      {
                              0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09,0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f
                      };

    ...
    AlgorithmParameterSpec params = new IvParameterSpec(ivar);

    encipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    encipher .init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, params);

...

public void writeTo(final OutputStream out) throws IOException {
              if (out == null) {
                  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Output stream may not be null");
              }
              try {

              out = new CipherOutputStream(out, encipher );


              int numRead = 0;
              while ( (count = in.read(buf)) !=-1) {
                out.write(buf, 0, count);


              }
              out.flush();
              in.close();

            }
            catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            }
          }
```

Please help me with the decryption problem. Maybe the binary files are missing 128 bits, too, but it is not so much remarkable except for text files content :( I heard that could happen because of incorrect sequence streams closing or so but I am not sure.

I heard it may be the InputStreamBody content length problem the method:

```
public long getContentLength() {

             return -1;


         }
```

But how to set the modified output length correctly if "in.length!=out.length" owing to the encryption (see writeTo method) ?

Please help me to fix this

Any useful comment is appreciated :)

Comment: Could you get us a sample file?

Comment: Ah, file-attaching does not work. If it is small enough, encode it with base64 and post the source, but better upload it somewhere and post a link. Or post the program which produced the file.

Comment: Here it is 
http://www.woofiles.com/dl-237412-jykMVBnT-files.rar

Comment: Why the file has characters lost?

Comment: I don't get it... Why video and even doc files I get downloaded fine except txt format? Is the txt format is something special?

Comment: Duplicate of [downloaded txt file become shrinked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505418/downloaded-txt-file-become-shrinked)

Comment: Do **never ever** write `catch (java.io.IOException e) {}` - this simply eats away your exception without you getting to know what it is. Use something like `catch (java.io.IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` at least (and look if there is something on the error output).

Comment: Did you create a subclass of InputStreamBody where you overwrite the method, or did you copy the class and change the method? (What you linked is not the documentation, but a source code view with unit test coverage report.)

Comment: No I just created a class which extends the InputStreamBody

Comment: But as for this case, yes it is the modified InputStreamBody itself... Because I needed to test it more closely for I don't get it why txt files never get their endings :(

Comment: So you think there is an exception may be?

Comment: I've check the catch block but there is no exception throws :( So then I tryed to check the buffer bits transffered ... upload sends 553 and download gets 496 + 32 (total 528). So the download get lost some 25 bytes :( Oh my... Where can it be?

Comment: Oh, I've just noticed that on the servlet side if txt file is uploaded the reauest content type is not finished as: Content Type =multipart/form-data; boundary=u_UM6G3ECVB-m_MX8Ia_rpYZ33sZjL-NE2lY9_

Comment: And for example a doc file content type boundary is : Content Type =multipart/form-data; boundary=BevJt9X-12tg8-uJnBfwBEK9_1y8xl

Comment: What can it be? Why the txt file make the boundary be unfinished? Or there is something missing?

Comment: The boundary simply is a string which delimits the parts of the multipart message, it can be anything, as long as it does not appear inside the parts itself. It is more or less randomly created by the uploading program. If you have a complete snapshot of the uploaded data, you should see it between the individual parts and at the end.

Comment: You could try my program to encrypt your file first to disk, and then send the encrypted file with your upload program (remove the encryption part). Then you can see whether there is some problem on the encryption or on the upload. And use some other program to look what you uploaded there (i.e. download it directly with scp or such).

Comment: But why does it happens with txt and html etc text files only? But doc files are fine ? I don't get it :(

Comment: As a test, I have just turned off the encryption and decryption code  and sonnet126.txt uploaded and downloaded perfectly :( So still the problem is in the encryption and decryption... Why the final text is getting lost? And why that happens with text files only?

Comment: That is a real mistery as for me :( Maybe the problem is in the txt encoding (Unicode) or something else but how that can effect the encryption?

Comment: maybe it is the upload parser bug or something... upload servlet code like a upload.parseRequest(request); ?

Comment: I disactivated the encrypt and decrypt code and all things upload fine even the txt files :( So it is the encryption problem. But is occures with text files only. I suspect the txt files do have non-adapted bits length or something like this... So the rest bits get lost because there is no 4096 bits at the end or I am not sure...

And what should me do if it is a bad padding error then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I made a test program to see how it works (see below).

It creates this file:

```
O thou, my lovely boy, who in thy power
Dost hold Time's fickle glass, his sickle, hour;
Who hast by waning grown, and therein show'st
Thy lovers withering as thy sweet self grow'st;
If Nature, sovereign mistress over wrack,
As thou goest onwards, still will pluck thee back,
She keeps thee to this purpose, that her skill
May time disgrace and wretched minutes kill.
Yet fear her, O thou minion of her pleasure!
She may detain, but not still keep, her treasure:
Her audit, though delay'd, answer'd must be,
And her quietus is to render thee.
```

Looks complete (and `diff` says it is identical to the input).

For why your program seems to cut something off, I have no idea.

The code you put in the question does not compile (needed some modifications, see below), and also uses a random key (from the key generator) instead of the key used to encrypt your example text file. I used a fixed key in my example below for reproducibility, but with a random key it also produces the same decrypted file (another encrypted file, obviously).

Run the class on your input file, and compare its encrypted output to your encrypted file (both on server and on client). Maybe this will help finding the problem.

Here the sample code.
The main method takes three file names as arguments, the first is the original file (and must exist), the second is the encrypted file, the third the decrypted (both will be overwritten if existing). If a fourth argument is given, it uses a random key.

```
package de.fencing_game.paul.examples;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;

public class EncryptDecrypt {


    AlgorithmParameterSpec params;

    public EncryptDecrypt()
        throws Exception
    {
        byte[] ivar = new byte[] {
            0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
            0x08, 0x09,0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f
        };
        params = new IvParameterSpec(ivar );
    }


    public void encrypt(SecretKey key, File from, File to)
        throws  Exception
    {
        Cipher ourCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        ourCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, params );
        crypt(ourCipher, from, to);
    }

    public void decrypt(SecretKey key, File from, File to)
        throws Exception
    {
        Cipher ourCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        ourCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, params );
        crypt(ourCipher, from, to);
    }


    private void crypt(Cipher c, File from, File to) 
        throws IOException
    {
        InputStream in = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(from), c);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(to);
        copyStream(in, out);
    }

    private void copyStream(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
        throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int count = 0;

        while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }


    public static void main(String[] params)
        throws Exception
    {
        EncryptDecrypt ed = new EncryptDecrypt();

        if(params.length > 3) {
            KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            kgen.init(128);
            SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
        }
        else {
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("AES");
            // AES needs 128 bits = 16 bytes
            KeySpec spec =
                new SecretKeySpec("Test-KeyTest-Key".getBytes("US-ASCII"),
                                  "AES");
            System.out.println(spec);

            SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            System.out.println(key);
        }


        ed.encrypt(key, new File(params[0]), new File(params[1]));
        ed.decrypt(key, new File(params[1]), new File(params[2]));
    }

}
```

Comment: ok, I am going to check it more deeply. I suspect the upload code may occure the problem but I am not sure because it works fine with the rest file formats? By the way I am using HttpClient 4 to upload files... Maybe there is a specification as for txt files but I couldn't find the information?

Comment: Are you using some transfer program which converts line endings? (But I would then except the output to be really broken, not simple the last line missing.)

Comment: Check the file size before and after uploading (and after downloading, before decrypting). Try to change the file name to something like `.dat` or such.

Comment: I am using InputStreamBody to upload file with multiform entity... There is a default mime type is application/octet-stream so maybe that could be the problem? But I am not sure...

Comment: code like a... multiPartEntity.addPart("file-stream", new InputStreamBody(new FileInputStream(encryptedFile),encryptedFile.getName()));

Comment: And, yes, you must be right concerning the length  because if you just look at the attached rar contetn more closely you notice the encrypted file is smaller than original and the decripted is smaller than encrypted... Maybe the encryption is getting fail with final block... How to check it?

Comment: How are you doing the encryption? (If you have code, add it to the question.)

Comment: I am making the encryption right inside the InputStreamBody writeTo method... I am going to show you

Comment: And, by the way, I have already changed the file extension from txt to anything else like dat etc but that didn't help... :(

Comment: I assume the text files are quite small and the binary files are quite big? Which is the deciding factor? What happens to a megabyte file containing only text? What happens to a single pixel GIF?

Comment: Another thought - Looking at the code for CipherInputStream and CipherOutputStream if you get a BadPaddingException on the final block you will get a truncated file and no visible Exception anywhere. The fact your files are getting smaller on each pass through CipherInputStream may mean it is a padding problem as the padding affects the final block.

Comment: How to check it? Should I make some test images in 1-3 px? Yes, video files are big and they all get well no matter their length was about 16.7Mb etc... But images (icons like) were fine too... So how to check it to find out for sure?

Comment: OK, I am going to test big and small files to tell you more detailed information... But how to fix the padding problem if there is such a thing takes place?

Comment: I have checked and I want to say that 3px image is corrupted and cannot be open and 5px and 10px images are OK... 4.4Mb txt file is missing final 23 characters :(

Comment: So it is the padding problem I guess... What causes the padding problem? And how to fix it in my case?

Comment: Help me to understand please.

Comment: You still did not really help us to identify the reason. Try to isolate encryption, uploading and downloading and decryption, and look after each at the file size to see where the file is cut off.

Comment: Well the files txt become truncated as I showed in the sample files I attached... I don't know but the BadPaddingException doesn't throw. That cutting off happens with all text files like txt. html,css etc...

3px png files are always corrupted after downloading but 5px and 10px are fine.

Comment: So as I can get it, the encryption may encrypt just filled up 4096 length blocks but doesn't want to encrypt a small rest block :( But why? Why all get well if to encryption occurs without uploading, as your code shows?

Comment: Please advise me the tests I should do to provide more detailed information concerning the padding check because I have just confused a little :)

Comment: Quote: "and look after each at the file size to see where the file is cut off"
I have done it before and I want to say that encription makes txt files smaller by their lengths. If I upload txt file and its original langth is 553Kb the encryption makes a 544Kb length file :(

Comment: client says 553bytes were uploaded and servlet says 544bytes were recieved. That cannot be.... but I just monitor the bytes read and write length during the uploading process and can see that...

Comment: Could this be a bug in either your server or uploading library? Did you try to change to the newest version?

Comment: I've just dwonloaded the libs and I think it is the newest libs apache can provide

Comment: commons-FileUpload v 1.2.2 and httpComponents v4.1 and commons-io v1.4

Comment: I thought that txt files are the first files which should be able to be uploaded (encrypted) with no problem because they are the simplest :) So I've never expected such a badluck :(

Comment: Sure it can be decrypted but the final text line is like a:

Original text:
"And her quietus is to render thee."  
Decrypted text:
"And her q"

Comment: As for servlet I am using Tomcat 6

Comment: And what about my newest question editing? How can I set content length if in.length!=out.length ?

Comment: You should not have to set the length - the `-1` means "I don't know the length yet, determine it from the end-of-stream". Alternatively you could encrypt your whole file first and then set the length of the encrypted data as the content length. But as long as you don't show a **complete** code sample from which the problem is reproducible, it is only plain guessing here.

Comment: Perhaps you right concerning the pre-encryption. Anyway thanks I am going to check all advices :)

Answer (score 1):

Is your servlet code specifying a content length?

The missing trailing bytes will be the final block of the cipher. The final block always requires special handling as it must be padded. The padding makes the encrypted file a few bytes larger than the original file. If your servlet sends the actual file's content length, the download will be truncated, the final improperly truncated and the output missing a few bytes.

It may be the binary files you are trying are an exact multiple of cipher blocks in size and hence do not require any padding.

Comment: So you want to say I am trying to upload a file with wrong length? But how to make the padded then?

Comment: Emm... I encripted video and audio not just the 128*N length... But they all are different :) But the txt files are always missing some final text... So I want to find out why but I need your fresh sight. OK I am going to show you the upload code snippet...

Comment: I've noticed when I try to upload any txt file the servlet request boundary is not finished. It ends with "_" ... For the sample file I attached the boundary is  :

Comment: "multipart/form-data; 
boundary=u_UM6G3ECVB-m_MX8Ia_rpYZ33sZjL-NE2lY9_"

Comment: but if I upload a doc file the request boundary is always finished like a:

Comment: "multipart/form-data; boundary=BevJt9X-12tg8-uJnBfwBEK9_1y8xl"

Comment: Quote: "Is your servlet code specifying a content length?"
yes I use FileUpload lib and there is code like a ServletFileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(fu.getFileItemFactory());
         upload.setSizeMax(100000000);

Comment: So I hope the 100000000 is enough to upload 553Kb txt file? Or I have missed the content length is?